# Can I safely modify a VB collection's items while iterating over it (using For Each)?

Tags: vb.net, collections, iterator

Can I safely modify -I mean: remove and re-add on a different index position- any item that I iterate over using a `For Each` loop in VB? We are talking about the VB `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` class.

And if yes: Is this by design, or an implementational detail, that I am building upon then?

I might be too lazy to search hard enough, but the dox don't seem to say anything about this.

Comment: I faintly remember I already did it successfully, but since I don't remember where I did it, I cannot be sure it wasn't just pure luck :|

Comment: BTW, the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` exists for VB6 compatibility and should not be used.  Instead, use a `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` from `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Under VBS, I can use only the VB collection, right? For reasons outside of the scope of this thread, I keep some code VBS compatible, so I use the VB Collection class under VB10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IEnumerator<T>` spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx) says that you can't:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

Some collections might not follow this rule.

Comment: I wonder especially if Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection does follow this rule. I think not, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a collection whilst iterating through it as you describe; i.e. you can't remove an item without getting an exception such as "collection was modified".

That's not to say you can't modify the items at all (do something other than add/remove).

If you run into this error, try refactoring your code e.g. using a `for` loop (often in reverse, to avoid offsetting the index counter).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Rather make a copy of the collection to edit and use the copy afterwards.